# Eloquent query for encrypted fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crypt

I am saving clients in my database and I am getting their invoices through their identity document. The document is encrypted and this client MAY EXIST SEVERAL TIMES in the database (since this client can belong to several users at the same time)

I am doing this query but it does not get me all the saved values

```
$nif = \Crypt::decryptString(\Auth::user()->userprofile->nif_dni_cif);

 $invoices = Invoices::whereHas('userclient', function($query) use($nif) {
            $query->where('nif', $nif);
        })
                ->where('status', 0)
                ->orWhereHas('userclient', function($query) use($nif) {
                    $query->where('nif', $nif);
                })
                ->orWhere('status', 2)
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

How can I solve that? Thanks

Comment: Your queries in `whereHas()` and `orWhereHas()` are identical... Did you mean to put that `where('status', ...)` and `orWhere('status', ...)` inside of them too?

Comment: Also, maybe your query would make more sense from the other direction; `UserClient::where('nif', $nif)->with(['invoices' => function($query){ $query->whereIn('status', [0, 2]); }])->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get()`

Comment: @TimLewis It does not matter. When I query ``'nif'`` and ``$nif`` they don't match and it doesn't show the results.

Comment: Ah, ok. If the `nif `column is being encrypted via `Crypt::encryptString` (or similar), the value will be different every time, and you can't reliably query against that column. You'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: @TimLewis Correct. That is my problem ... How could I solve it? Could you help me?

Comment: Use a different, non-encrypted column to query against... Beyond that vague advice, I can't really help you solve this issue, as it's going against the purpose of encryption...